# How to reuse logic in a context sensitive way in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to figure out the best way to organize a ASP.NET MVC site. Take a very simple 1..N relationship: Company can have many Contacts, Contacts must have exactly one Company.

I have your typical routes:

- Company/Index (list all companies)
- Company/Details/{int} (details of Company {int})
- Company/Create (create new company)
- Contact/Index (list all contacts)
- Contact/Create (create new contact, company is selected from drop down)

Now if I wanted to create a page that created a Contact in the context of a Company (from the Company detail page) so that the required company is filled in/not editable), what would be the best route of going about that, while not duplicating code where possible.

Not sure if I can leverage the Contact/Create logic/view from the Company controller (and be able to route back to the Company Details page when complete), or mess with the routes to do something like Company/Details/{int}/Contact/Create (not even sure if that makes sense or would work)?

There has got to be a better way then me adding my logic and view for adding a Contact into my Controller view and having it duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant find the link, but found some information about using named routes to help out :)